# gradle add dependency best practice group-name-version vs string

Tags: gradle

gradle dependency can be added with

`compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.7'`

and

`compile 'org.apache.commonse:commons-lang3: '3.7'`

It appears that there is no real difference.
Which one is considered a better practice and why?

Comment: It makes no difference at all - what matters is consistency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No difference at all.

If you searched the jar in [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.7), the dependency format is like the first one, while if you searched it in [Bintray](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/org.apache.commons:commons-lang3), the format would be the second one. I'd prefer the latter due to the simplicity.